# Disable all WordPress & WooCommerce attribute archives

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, archive

I want to disable all attribute archives from woocommerce / wordpress. I already found following code which doesn't the job 100%. The problem is that when I crawl the website the attribute archive pages still exist. I need them to never show in the frontend.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_wp_archives');
 
function remove_wp_archives(){
  if( is_archive() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404(); //set to 404 not found page
  }
}
```

thx

Comment: You need to uncheck "Enable archives?" setting checkbox for each product attribute…

Comment: I have a lot of attributes and the problem is that somehow the "enable archive" checkbox is checked even if I uncheck it...

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL as another suggested. This sets all Attribute archives to Off.

```
update wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies set attribute_public = '0' where attribute_public = '1';
```

This is correct

Once complete go to
WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Recount Terms

WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Regenerate product lookup tables

This will refresh your tables

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```sql
UPDATE wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies SET attribute_public = 0 WHERE attribute_public = 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).